# C++ boost::chrono vs std:chrono time since epoch (get current system time) in windows

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, window

I tried to use boost/chrono.... 
using boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
I am not able to get the current system time instead I get Thu Jan 01 09:53:53 1970... but with std::chrono I am able to get the correct system time.

How to get current system time using boost/chrono same as std:: chrono?

Answer (score 0):

To get the system time, use `system_clock` not `high_resolution_clock`.

There's no guarantee, in either Boost or the standard library, that `high_resolution_clock` will use the same epoch as the system clock.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple math

```
boost::posix_time::ptime const time_epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970, 1, 1));

auto ms = (boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time() - time_epoch).total_microseconds();
std::cout << "microseconds: " << ms << "\n";

boost::posix_time::ptime now = time_epoch + boost::posix_time::microseconds(ms);
std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_iso_string(now);
```

More samples:

- [time since epoch to string using boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738609/time-since-epoch-to-string-using-boost/26739139#26739139)
- [Actual millis in a C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879698/actual-millis-in-a-c/22879764#22879764)
- [Creating a boost::posix_time::ptime object from a 64 bit integer second count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379077/creating-a-boostposix-timeptime-object-from-a-64-bit-integer-second-count/19382087#19382087) (custom epoch)